# Как выполнить поиск записей в Postgresql, где в подстроке число , которое меньше заданной величины

Tags: postgresql

Есть таблица и в ней поле agent. Это строка

> fr. 7.2.5 (950) / iPhone (iOS 155) / x86_64

> fr. 7.25.5 (950) / iPhone (iOS 155) / x86_64

> fr. 7.225.5 (950) / iPhone (iOS 155) / x86_64

Вот запрос

```sql
select * from some_table where agent ilike '%7.2%ios%
```

Для того, чтобы найти не только нужные цифры но и определенные слова (нужно было отобрать строки, которые содержат 'ios'), пришлось сделать так (выражение with cte ... предоставил @Akina)

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp1 AS
SELECT *
FROM some_table rt
WHERE rt.agent ilike '%ios%';

select * from temp1;

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT agent, regexp_split_to_array(agent, '\D+') parts
    FROM temp1
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE parts[2] :: INT < 7
   OR parts[3] :: INT < 105;
```

**Update** (решение за один запрос)

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT agent, regexp_split_to_array(agent, '\D+') parts
    FROM reactive_table
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE cte.agent ilike '%ios%'
  and (parts[2] :: INT < 8
    OR parts[3] :: INT < 105
    );
```

Как найти все строки, где версия ниже чем 7.104 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT agent, regexp_split_to_array(agent, '\D+') parts
  FROM test
)
SELECT agent
FROM cte
WHERE parts[2] :: INT < 7 
   OR parts[3] :: INT < 104;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KDwtVEvQ)

Comment: да. это то что надо. а как можно задать дополнительное выражение, нужно чтобы еще нашлись только те строки, где упоминается ios

Comment: @skyho Добавить соотв. условие во WHERE...